# Google Search Console API not returning enough data

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, google-search-console

https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/searchanalytics/query

Google Analytics tells me ~20k pages were visited from Google search, but the Google Search Console API returns just under 5k urls. Changing `startRow` doesn't help.

What's really odd is I've connected Google Search Console to Google Analytics, and when viewing GSC data in GA (Acquisition -> Search Console -> Landing Pages) the GSC data there also gives me ~20k rows.

How do I get all ~20k rows out of the Google Search Console API?

```
date_str = '2017-12-20'
start_index = 0
row_limit = 5000
next_index = 5000
rows = []
while next_index == row_limit:
  req = webmasters_service.searchanalytics().query(
      siteUrl='https://tenor.com/',
      fields='responseAggregationType,rows',
      body={
          "startDate": date_str,
          "endDate": date_str,
          "searchType": search_type,
          "dimensions": [
              "page",
          ],
          "rowLimit": row_limit,
          "startRow": start_index,
      },
  )
  try:
      resp = req.execute()
      next_rows = resp['rows']
      rows += next_rows
      next_index = len(next_rows)
      start_index += next_index
  except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      break
return rows
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else viewing this post:

When I view 'Search Results' under 'Performance' in the sidebar of the google search console webpage, at the end of the url there is a variable 'resource_id=sc-domain%3example.com'. I recommend using this resource_id variable as your siteURL.